# Render image Open GLES android ndk

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I need to render an image through Open GLES in android native code. The byte array of the image is generated in the java code and sent to the native code as a parameter.But rendering through native code shows a black screen always. The native code is:

```
 JNIEXPORT int JNICALL
    Java_com_example_hellojni_MyView_renderByEgl(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, jobject surface,
                                                 jint width, jint height, jbyteArray byteArray_) {
        EGLDisplay display;
        EGLConfig config;
        EGLContext context;
        EGLSurface eglSurface;
        ANativeWindow* pWindow = ANativeWindow_fromSurface(env, surface);
        EGLint num_config;
        display = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
        eglInitialize(display, NULL, NULL);
        eglBindAPI(EGL_OPENGL_ES_API);
        eglChooseConfig(display, attribute_list, &config, 1, &num_config);
        context = eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, NULL);
        eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface(display, config, pWindow, NULL);
        eglMakeCurrent(display, eglSurface, eglSurface, context);
        jboolean isCopy;
        unsigned char * pCData = (unsigned char*)(*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, byteArray_, &isCopy);
        if(isCopy)
        {
            (*env)-> ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, byteArray_, pCData, JNI_ABORT);
        }
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,10,10,width,height,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,pCData);
     glFlush();
        eglSwapBuffers(display, eglSurface);
        sleep(10);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OpenGL code is completely wrong with many fundamental mistakes; you don't seem to have any geometry, shader programs, or make any draw calls. The call to `glTexImage2D` simply uploads data to a texture object (which you don't have), it doesn't render anything to the screen ...

Start by learning the basics using some of the Android SDK (if you want Java) or Android NDK (if you want native code) OpenGL ES tutorials and get texturing working there first. Learn the basics, and worry about interacting NDK with Java as a second step ...

Comment: I just want to render an image.Is there a way to write a buffer to the EGLSurface?